# Display data horizontally in MS Access report

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

I am currently working with a MS Access database, which should store courses and their participants. Each course has multiple course days and I want to create a report on which the teacher can tick (if printed out) if the student is attending the current lesson.

Therefore I would like to display the names of the participants vertically and the course dates horizontally, but I got stuck at this point.

Like in the screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: Look into crosstab queries.

Comment: Edit question to show raw data as text tables. I don't think crosstab will get you want you want - which seems to be a bunch of blank columns with date headers.